# PHP array is having a gap when printed out

Tags: php, arrays

This is the output of my 2 arrays:

code1:

```
     print_r($arr);
     echo implode(" ", $arr) ."\n";
```

output:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    
        [2] => 3
    )
    1 2
     3
```

code 2:

```
     print_r($arr);
     echo implode(" ", $arr) ."\n";
```

output

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 2
    
        [3] => 3
    )
    1 4 2
     3
```

Why do my arrays have a gap in them? This happens after I do some swapping of code in my project in order to sort the numbers (special case, can't sort($arr) ).

Edit: I did `var_dump($arr);` on both the array's, here is the output:
code 1:

```
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "2
    "
      [2]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
```

code 2:

```
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "2
    "
      [2]=>
      string(1) "3"
      [3]=>
      string(1) "4"
    }
```

FUll code:

Content inside stdin file

```
    3
    3
    3 1 2
    4
    1 3 4 2
    5
    1 2 3 5 4
```

code:

```
    <?php
    $_fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    fscanf ($_fp, "%d", $testcases);
        
    for ($i = 0; $i < $testcases; $i++)
    {
        fscanf($_fp, "%d", $n);
        $arr = explode(" ", fgets($_fp));
        
            
        for ($j = 0; $j < ($n-1); $j++)
        {
            print_r($arr);
            if ($arr[$j] > $arr[$j+1])
            {            
                if ( isset($arr[$j-1]) )
                {
                    
                    
                    $loop = 0;
                    while($loop < 3)
                    {
                        $a = $arr[$j-1]; 
                        $b = $arr[$j]; 
                        $c = $arr[$j+1];
                        
                        $arr[$j-1] = $b;
                        $arr[$j] = $c;
                        $arr[$j+1] = $a;
                        
                        if ($arr[$j-1] <= $arr[$j] && $arr[$j] <= $arr[$j+1])
                        {
                            $possible = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        $loop++;
                    }
                    
                }
                elseif ( isset($arr[$j+2]) )
                {
                    $loop = 0;
                    while($loop < 3)
                    {
                        $a = $arr[$j]; 
                        $b = $arr[$j+1]; 
                        $c = $arr[$j+2];
    
                        
                        $arr[$j] = $b;
                        $arr[$j+1] = $c;
                        $arr[$j+2] = $a;
                        
                        if ($arr[$j] <= $arr[$j+1] && $arr[$j+1] <= $arr[$j+2])
                        {
                            $possible = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        $loop++;
                    }
                }
                
                
            }        
        }
        
        $possible = 0;
        
        print_r($arr);
        
        }
    
    
         ?>
```

Comment: var_dump($arr[1]); I think it containd newline symbols

Comment: Please provide complete code.

Comment: Added var_dump in my quesiton @splash58

Comment: Your second index has a newline character in it.

Comment: Also added the code which created this problem @VinayakSinha

Comment: But I cannot figure out, how to fix this problem.  I updated my questions, are you able find out the problem, in my code?

Comment: To fix use `trim()`

Comment: @Toby, It comes before code in your question. Look how you init [2] items

Comment: We can't tell you *why* one of your array elements has a new-line in it unless you post the code that produces the array in the first place.

Comment: Added full code, and thanks for trim advice

Comment: add `array_map('trim', $arr);` after `$arr = explode(" ", fgets($_fp));`

Comment: Works perfectly @splash58 What you did there?  I am really very curious

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: array_map use trim function for all item of the array - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for such a great information. It will solve many problems in some of my code ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array 2nd value has newline char

See [Demo](https://eval.in/902376)

```
<?php

  $arr = array(1,'2'.PHP_EOL,3);
  print_r($arr);
  echo implode(" ", $arr);
?>
```

Would produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2

    [2] => 3
)
1 2
 3
```

--edit--

Solution :

`$arr = array_map('trim', $arr);` after `$arr = explode(" ", fgets($_fp));`  because when reading a file using `fgets()` it will include the newline at the end. using `trim()` you can strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string, you may use `rtrim()` which strips whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

Comment: Thanks for the great info. But I cannot figure out, how to fix this problem.  I updated my question, are you able find out the problem, in my code?