# How do I trim '\n' in multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Output of `var_dump($arr)`

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "4
"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "7"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "8
"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "9"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "11"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "12
"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "13"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "14"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "15"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "16"
  }
}
```

i Want to remove `\n` in $arr array.

I tried to use `array_walk($arr,'intval');` but it did not work, because it is multiple dimensional array. What's the solution?

Is there any inbuilt PHP function? Or I need to use loops and remove it?

P.S: I am a newbie, try not to get too technical.

Comment: Yeah, by `\n` i mean, a link break.

Comment: @FirstOne yes, it is on `4`, `8` and `12`.

Comment: `array_walk` has a sibling name `array_walk_recursive` ...

Comment: use simple trim() in a loop through your array

Comment: Isn’t this the same issue you’ve been discussing here already, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47352713/1427878 …?

Comment: `array_walk_recursive($arr,'intval');` did not work. Same result

Comment: This is multi dimensional array @CBroe

Comment: I am aware of that. My point is more, why are _you_ not able to adapt an existing solution you already have for a single array? Does it really need a new question every time the situation changes ever so slightly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this via loop and [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$arr = array(
    array("1", "2", "3", "4\n"),
    array("5", "6", "7", "8\n"),
    array("9", "10", "11", "12\n"),
    array("13", "14", "15", "16\n"),
);

// result array
$result = [];

// Loop thru array
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    // Map thru $value with trim to remove \n then push to result
    $result[] = array_map('trim', $value);
}

// Output
echo('<pre>');
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 13):

You can just do

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function(&$v) { $v = trim($v); });
```

You cannot use `trim` directly as the callback, because it doesn't accept arguments by reference, so you have to wrap it in a callback that does.

**Demo** https://eval.in/904410

Comment: This is it, one-line superior answer of this question.

Comment: @JasomDotnet thanks. Most coding standards will make it a seven liner though ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are alternatives, but recursively looping through your array gives you flexibility about what to remove, not only newlines:

```
function removeNewline($array) {
  $result = array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // If the array value is an array itself, call the function recursively
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $result[$key] = removeNewline($value);
    } else {
      // Only remove newlines from strings
      if (is_string($value)) {
        $result[$key] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $value);
      } else {
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Note that there is a built-in function for that _recursively walk the array_. [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Comment: Yes I saw that answer just after I posted this. It probably is faster than my function.

Comment: I don't know about speed, but there is also another aspect about not reinventing the wheel. When using built-in / well-known functions / tools, you can count on them being tested and optimized (at least on the majority of the times). It is a good brain exercise, anyways.